# Firefox addon sdk get client ip return wrong format

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

```
var dns = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIDNSService);                         
var myName = dns.myHostName;
var record = dns.resolve(myName, 0);
while (record && record.hasMore()){
    console.log(record.getNextAddrAsString())
}
```

It return "2001:0:9d38:6abd:248d:2ee4:3f57:fd26"(255.255.255.255 subnet mask). How to get IP4.
Thank you so much.

Comment: That looks like it's returning you a IPv6, so you'd need so somehow convert back to human readable, dotted IP.

Comment: But i want ip4. Thank

Comment: The example I just gave you is IPv4 in the answer below... `long2ip()` converts a longip into a IPv4 IP.

Comment: This solution is wrong. You should be implementing IPv6 proper instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in JavaScript unfortunately, but assuming we follow standards for a IPv6 address I came up with this

```
function ipv62long( $chrp ) {
    $chr = '';
    foreach ( unpack('C*', inet_pton( $chrp ) ) as $byte ) {
        $chr .= str_pad( decbin( $byte ), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
    }
    return base_convert( ltrim($chr, '0' ), 2, 10 );
}

$chrp = ipv62long('2001:0:9d38:6abd:248d:2ee4:3f57:fd26');
echo $chrp;
echo '<p>' . long2ip( $chrp ) . '</p>';
```

Again, not sure about JavaScript, but if you can communicate with this script you could easily provide it the IPv6 and have it return the human readable IP.

```
function ipv62long( $chrp ) {
    $chr = '';
    foreach ( unpack('C*', inet_pton( $chrp ) ) as $byte ) {
        $chr .= str_pad( decbin( $byte ), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
    }
    return base_convert( ltrim($chr, '0' ), 2, 10 );
}

$chrp = ipv62long( urldecode( $_GET['v6'] ) );
echo "{'ip': '" . long2ip( $chrp ) . "'}"; // Return a JSON response
```

We get a response with a URI query like `ipv6.php?v6=2001%3a0%3a9d38%3a6abd%3a248d%3a2ee4%3a3f57%3afd26` which has the IP encoded for URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The format looks OK to me; I see a console output of both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

If you want to limit the output to only IPv4 addresses, you can pass a RESOLVE_DISABLE_IPV6 flag to the resolve function.

```
var dns = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIDNSService);                         
var myName = dns.myHostName;
var record = dns.resolve(myName, Ci.nsIDNSService.RESOLVE_DISABLE_IPV6);
while (record && record.hasMore()){
    console.log(record.getNextAddrAsString())
}
```

Comment: record.getNextAddrAsString();record.getNextAddrAsString(); two times is ip4. This worked with me

Answer (score 1):

You need to do "createInstance" instead of "getService"

`var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");` //have to do this

`var dns = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDNSService);`

`var myName = dns.myHostName;`

`var nsrecord = dns.resolve(myName, 0);` //resolve hostname

`while (nsrecord && nsrecord.hasMore()){
console.log("IP address: " + nsrecord.getNextAddrAsString());}` //logs to console